# Creating a swirling line effect on a letter or object in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I'm back with a question, does anyone has an idea on how te create this swirl effect on a letter, or an stroke in illustrator?

Looks so difficult to create, just curious if there is any easy way for this, and if probably anyone knows this.

Image link/creator: Pragmatika Design Studio

[image]

Comment: this looks 3D like your other question

Comment: THere is a error that wouldnt be there if it actually was made in 3d @Luciano So this one was made in 2d

Comment: @joojaa which error, the flat ends? I can't see anything else, but even that I can see it done with a 3D model

Comment: @Luciano there is one more band than what can be deduced from the pattern at the bottom. Anyway that might have been done when tracing

Comment: @Luciano, the flat ends disturb me to no end...

Comment: I think it is created in illustrator as a flat object but with a 3D look and feel. But I don't think it is handmade. It probably is achieved by applying a tool or certain technique.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact proof of user G.Falla's claim, but at least the result resembles the wanted swirliness. White is replaced here with light green to make parts visible:

[image]

1. Four equal adjacent horizontal rectangles, no stroke!
2. Two opposite tapered copies were made. The nodes at the other end are moved with the direct selection tool to a single point.
3. The tapered shapes make together a rectangle of the same size as the parts in image 1. The new rectangle is moved to the brushes collection and defined to be an artistic brush.
4. The brush is tried to a simple curve
5. Two curves are draw to opposite directions (as well you can make a reversed copy of the brush), the brush is applied and the width tool is applied. The parts are also shown as moved apart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ***absolutely*** *sure* one ***could*** draw this in illustrator with some care and thought; that said, *if* ***I*** *were tasked* with creating something of like kind *myself*, I'd choose to do it in a **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) app like [**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo), [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), [**C4D**](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/), [**Maya**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview), [**3DS**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview) or [**Lightwave**](https://www.lightwave3d.com/) - in my case I know I'd use [**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) 'cos that's my jam, it's super-artist-friendly, and it'd be pretty quick to accomplish there.

Comment: This came to mind because I think I saw it recently: https://youtu.be/FdNtkTCyzOA?t=886 - A little bit more abstract, but the same idea... Or one of the ways to do it.